# How to get the content of windows environment in python?

Tags: python

In Windows command prompt, I can  use

```
set
```

to get the content of the system environment.

Is it possible to get this in python?

This only get python related path:

```
In [3]: import sys

In [4]: sys.path
Out[4]:
['',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\python34.zip',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'c:\\Anaconda3',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.2.3-py3.4.egg',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\flake8-2.2.5-py3.4.egg',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\mccabe-0.2.1-py3.4.egg',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\runipy-0.1.1-py3.4.egg',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-7.0-py3.4.egg',
 'c:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'c:\\Users\\Nick\\.ipython']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import os
import pprint
pprint.pprint(os.environ)
```

`os.environ` is a dictionary mimicking the environment you're looking for.  Here, I'm just pretty-printing it, for readability.  But of course you can check all the keys, check what's for a specific key, whatever -- all the multitudinous operations possible on a dictionary!

**Modifying** `os.environ` won't affect "upstream" processes, such as the `cmd.exe` that spawned your Python program; there's no direct way to do that.  However, it **will** affect "downstream" processes, such as programs you could run from here with `os.system`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is quite clear solution. BTW: On my system, (`python3.4` and `pyton2.7`), there's no difference in appearance whether I use `pprint` or not.

Answer (score 1):

This will call **SET** from python as though it were a shell command.  The output is stored in the variable **out**.

```
import subprocess
setcmd = subprocess.Popen(["set"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, error = setcmd.communicate()
print out
```

For more information on subprocess and why using **shell=True** is a security hazard see here:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: It is good to know that python could communicate with native system shell. While it seems like cheating, using `!set` in `ipython` got the same result. Thanks a lot!